# Angular html template as string with style attribute renders with NO style attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I am having a Util.ts which defines format function as shown below. The problem is on the small tag which has style property.

```
export const formatMessage = (message ) =>{
    return '<b>' + message.name+" </b><small style ='color:black;'>" +message.ts + '</small>  ' + message.c;
  }
```

However when rendered small tag's style attribute is getting removed.

[image]

I am not sure why this behavior, The HTML string template returned by the formatMessage function is attached to the HTML using innerHTML of DIV as shown here.

```
<ul style="list-style-type: none;">
  <li  *ngFor="let each of messages"><div class='messageStyle' [innerHTML]="each"> </div></li>
</ul>
```

Why is this style property getting removed (while class property stays) and how do I address the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

dom sanitizer stips the style from your html. it is done to prevent xss attacks. you can bypass security checks by doing this:

```
  constructor(private s: DomSanitizer) { }
...
  export const formatMessage = (message, sanitizer ) =>{
    return sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml('<b>' + message.name+" </b><small style ='color:black;'>" +message.ts + '</small>  ' + message.c);
  }
```

and pass sanitizer to formatMessage

Comment: thanks for the answer, just realize that class property works.  can see class property however not finding class looking into it. I will mark your answer as answer after checking.